# SQL Server returns wrong result with trailing spaces in Where clause

Tags: sql-server

These queries all return the same result of one record

```
SELECT COUNT([partnr]) 
FROM [dbo].[tblPart] 
WHERE [partnr] = 'SIE.3RV1021-1EA10, In=2,8-4 A SHS UL   '

SELECT COUNT([partnr]) 
FROM [dbo].[tblPart] 
WHERE [partnr] = 'SIE.3RV1021-1EA10, In=2,8-4 A SHS UL      '

SELECT COUNT([partnr]) 
FROM [dbo].[tblPart] 
WHERE [partnr] = 'SIE.3RV1021-1EA10, In=2,8-4 A SHS UL            '
```

The result should be zero (0).

Only with this one it should be one.

```
SELECT COUNT([partnr]) 
FROM [dbo].[tblPart] 
WHERE [partnr] = 'SIE.3RV1021-1EA10, In=2,8-4 A SHS UL'
```

What am I doing wrong or do I need to change?

EDIT:

Thank you Bhasyakarulu Kottakota. Solution:

```
SELECT COUNT([partnr]) 
FROM [dbo].[tblPart] 
WHERE [partnr] LIKE 'SIE.3RV1021-1EA10, In=2,8-4 A SHS UL   '
```

Comment: You can refer to this article about that exact problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces

Comment: Please use "like" instead of "=". Since this is the default behavior of SQL Server (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626).